# Javascript prototype: how do I call a method within another method?

Tags: javascript, prototype

This is my first attempt to javascript prototyping.  I am using the Espruino(javascript interpreter for microcontrollers) to get data from environment sensors. I am trying to pause my code for 1000ms, then execute the getSensorReading() method which is(I think) located inside of another method. How do I execute getSensorReading() method?  I believe the error is cause by this:

```
setTimeout(function (e) { this.getSensorReading(); }, w); //Attempting to execute getSensorReading()
```

I am receiving this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Function "getSensorReading" not found!  at line 1 col 8 { this.getSensorReading(); }
        ^ in function called from system
```

Code:

```
I2C1.setup({scl:b6, sda:b7});

function Sensor (theType, theAddress) {
  this.type = theType;   //i.e. PH
  this.address = theAddress;  //i2c Address
  this.sensorResult = 0; //Store sensor result
  this.cmdTable = {
    "Calibrate" : {  //List of Calibration commands and timeout value.
      "clear" : { "cmd" : "Cal,Clear",      "wait" : 300  },
      "mid"   : { "cmd" : "Cal,mid,7.00",   "wait" : 1300 },
      "low"   : { "cmd" : "Cal,low,4.00",   "wait" : 1300 },
      "high"  : { "cmd" : "Cal,high,10.00", "wait" : 1300 },
      "query" : { "cmd" : "Cal,?",          "wait" : 300  }
    },
    "Information" : {  //Device Information

    },
    "LED" : {  //Enable / Disable or Query the LEDs
      "L0" : { "cmd" : "L,0", "wait" : 300 },
      "L1" : { "cmd" : "L,1", "wait" : 300 },
      "L?" : { "cmd" : "L,?", "wait" : 300 }
    },
    "Reading" : {  //Takes a single reading
      "R" : { "cmd" : "R,25.6", "wait" : 1000 } //Takes a single temperature compensated reading
    },
    "Serial"      : {  //Switch back to UART mode

    },
    "Sleep"       : {  //Enter low power sleep mode

    },
    "Status"      : {  //Retrieve status information

    },
    "Temperature" : {  //Set or Query the temperature compensation
      "T"  : { "cmd" : "T,19.5", "wait" : 300 },  //Where the temperature is any value; floating point, or int, in ASCII form
      "T?" : { "cmd" : "T,?",   "wait" : 300 }  //Query the set temerature
    },
    "Factory"     : {  //Factory reset

    },
  };
}

Sensor.prototype = {
  constructor: Sensor,
  getSensorType:function () {
    return this.type; //Get Sensor type
  },
  getSensorAddress:function () {
    return this.address; //Get Sensor address
  },
  getSensorReading:function() {
    a = this.getSensorAddress;
    console.log("i2c Address: " + a);
    //d = I2C1.readFrom(a, 7);
    return d;
  },
  getSensorResult:function () {
    a = this.getSensorAddress;
    c = this.cmdTable.Reading.R.cmd;
    w = this.cmdTable.Reading.R.wait;

    //I2C1.writeTo(a, c);
    setTimeout(function (e) { this.getSensorReading(); }, w); //Attempting to execute getSensorReading()
  },
  storeSensorResult:function () {

  },
  updateResTemp:function (temp) {
    console.log("Before: " + this.cmdTable.Reading.R.cmd);
    this.cmdTable.Reading.R.cmd = "R," + temp;
    console.log("After: " + this.cmdTable.Reading.R.cmd);
  }
};

var ph = new Sensor("ph", 0x63);

ph.updateResTemp(90.5);
ph.getSensorResult();
```

Comment: Look into [how `this` works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword) and `Function.prototype.bind`. Also, you forgot to declare all your local variables; you need to use `var`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code "this" in `setTimeout` callback refers the parent function `getSensorResult`. That function doesn't have a function called `getSensorReading`. That's the reason for the error... Also as you are using global variables inside function unexpected results may occur by overbidding the variables. Make them global with `var` keyword.
Try changing like this..

```
getSensorReading:function() {
    var a = this.getSensorAddress;
    console.log("i2c Address: " + a);
    //var d = I2C1.readFrom(a, 7);
    return d;
  },
getSensorResult:function () {
    var a = this.getSensorAddress;
    var c = this.cmdTable.Reading.R.cmd;
    var w = this.cmdTable.Reading.R.wait;
    var that = this;
    //I2C1.writeTo(a, c);
    setTimeout(function (e) { that.getSensorReading(); }, w); //Attempting to execute getSensorReading()
  }
```

Comment: SO I can better understand this.  The reason why var that = this works is because this points to the parent: Sensor.prototype allowing me to call getSensorReading?

Comment: "this" in "that = this" points to the object "ph" not to the Sensor.prototype. "that" is a global variable to the function "ph.getSensorResult". Because of that you can access the parent of "ph.getSensorResult" with "that".

Answer (score 1):

Declare global method `foo` and sub-method `bar` and refer to sub-method as function in itself, you can use `this` keyword inside sub-method by addressing previously declared variable, and then declare the return variable as the sub-method process.

```
Foo: function()
{
    var a='a';
    var ret='b';

    var Bar = function()
    {
        this.a='a';
        return 'a';    
    }

    ret=Bar();

    return ret; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with looking into `this`, `Function.prototype.bind`, and also the prototype chain in general. Also, javascript is a dynamically bound language. You can re-bind `this`.

you can either store a reference to this as a closure variable, or bind the function literal that you're passing to `setTimeout` to the context you want (`Sensor.prototype` or `this` in that context)

EDIT: In lieu of having `bind` available, you can accomplish the same thing with apply, call, or closures.

```
getSensorResult:function () {
    a = this.getSensorAddress;
    c = this.cmdTable.Reading.R.cmd;
    w = this.cmdTable.Reading.R.wait;

    //I2C1.writeTo(a, c);
    setTimeout((function(_this) {
      return function (e) {
        _this.getSensorReading();
      }
    })(this), w); //Attempting to execute getSensorReading()
}
```

Comment: I researched .bind(this) and found out that .bind is not supported by Espruino; however, the developer stated that it is on his to do list.